# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from 14.04.03 LTS migration + nvidia GTX 960 : problems

Tags: drivers, unity, nvidia, 16.04, graphics

First of all sorry for my English, I am not native ;)

I recently migrate to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my workstation which embeds a Nvidia GTX 960 graphic card.
After the migration, I tried every nvidia driver installations (latest propiretary one and also the ppa stable ones). I did follow every topics trying to reinstall Xorg, compiz, ubuntu desktop, ... but nothing works. I am not in secure boot mode in EFI.

after some nvidia drivers installation it is looping in the logging display. With some others, I can log but i have only a flat desktop without any unity launcher nor menu bar.

Some ideas?

Thanks in advance.
Next time I will wait for a while before migrating to a new LTS.

Best,
Guilmort